# Johnson-Neyman plots for glmer models (logistic, mixed effects) in R against non-zero values

Tags: r, logistic, statistical-significance, mixed-model, interaction

Note: this is a different question from the one I asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/589616), but I'm using the same example model.

I have an `R glmer` (logisitc mixed-effects) model that looks something like:

```
mod <- glmer(choice ~ (x1+ x2)*log(x3) +x4 +(x1 + x2 | id), data = dat, family = binomial)
```

I can get the slopes of the interaction between x1 and x3 by doing:

```
slopes <- modelbased::estimate_slopes(mod, trend = "x1", at = "x3", length=50)
```

And then plot the significance of x1 across values of x3 (i.e. look at the Johnson-Neyman plot):

```
plot(slopes)
```

This tells me at what point of x3 the effects of x1 become significantly different from 0. But what if I had a non-zero value to test against? Let's say I want to find out when x1 becomes significantly different from another distribution, with mean mu and standard deviation sigma. I estimated this other distribution using the following model in a different dataset:

```
mod2 <- glmer(choice ~ x1+ x2 + x4 +(x1 + x2 | id), data = dat2, family = binomial)
```

I want to compare the difference between the coefficients of x1 in the two datasets across values of x3 for the first dataset. So my test distribution is the coefficient of x1 in mod2. Let's say x3 represents someone's age. I want to know at what age the mod coefficient for x1 becomes the same/different from the mod2 coefficient for x1.

I can get a Johnson-Neyman plot for the x1's coefficients for the first dataset and offset them by mu by doing:

```
slopes <- modelbased::estimate_slopes(mod, trend = "x1", at = "x3", length=50, offset=mu)
plot(slopes)
```

But how can I take into account the standard deviation/variance of my test distribution too?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "when [the effects of?] x1 becomes significantly different from another distribution, with mean mu and standard deviation sigma." Is that some theoretical distribution or one estimated from the same data set? And just what go you mean by "different from" in this context? It might help if you edited the question to be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish, with more details about your data and your model, as there might be a better way to proceed than what you presently have in mind.

Comment: @EdM is this better?

Comment: Are the data sets for the 2 models completely different? In what ways? Is it possible to combine the 2 data sets into a single model? If not, why not? E.g., are there no `x3` values available for the second data set? Usually, a single combined model will provide more power than trying to compare across models like this.